# What does the 'g' mean under VIRT in "top" on linux?

Tags: linux, centos

The output from "top" for a server of mine says this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
64860 mongod    20   0 16.721g  81016  16820 R  0.7  4.7  18:37.66 mongod
```

under VIRT - does the g mean "GB"?

Comment: Great Brtian no, GigaBytes yes.  Try 'man top' or see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html for more info.

Comment: hehe, thank you that's very helpful (and FAR more helpful than those on Server Fault).  Want to put this as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Great Brtian no, GigaBytes yes. Try 'man top' or see man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html for more info.